# color datagridview cell and the one next to it based on condition

Tags: vb.net

my code below only change color of 1 cell based on text value. How can I change color of a cell and the one on the next column based on same value. thanks

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting


     If Not DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
        If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns("Dept1").Index Then
            If Not IsDBNull(e.Value) Then
                If e.Value = "Staring" Then
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray

                    e.CellStyle.Font = New Font("Arial", 16.0F)


                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1)
```

Something like:

```
If Not DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
  If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns("Dept1").Index Then
    If Not IsDBNull(e.Value) Then
      If e.Value = "Staring" Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        e.CellStyle.Font = New Font("Arial", 16.0F)

        Dim otherCell As DataGridViewCell =
          DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex + 1)

        otherCell.Style.BackColor = e.CellStyle.BackColor
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
```

References:

- [DataGridView.Rows @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows).
- [DataGridViewCell.Style @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.style%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you help, I had to change from DataColumn to DataGridViewColumn because I got an exception. but even that, it colored the whole column instead of the cell beside the 1st cell that meet the condition

Comment: @user3216067: Sorry, I was thinking something else when answering this question. Please check my edit.